# regex non-capturing in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I've a strings like:

```
{
 "root": {
 "var": "123"
},

 "subject": {
  "address": {
  "phone": "string",
  "mail": [
     "string"
```

my regex looks like this \"([^\"]*)\" I want strings in quotations marks to be matched but not in case where there're only one pair of quotation and nothing else in a line - like in last line: "string"

any help?

Comment: use online regexp helpers. like: https://regexr.com/ or https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example, this regex returns all strings where there is a leading colon `:` (therefore if there is no colon like the last line, there is no match), or there is trailing space and colon.

`\"(.+)\"(?=:)|(?<=: )\"(.+)\"`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/7)

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider giving a green tick and upvote if it helped! :)